# Sequential promise loop with delay

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm attempting to load an array of "requests" sequentially each one separated by a delay.

I'm using promises but for some reasons I'm having issues with the requests being executed in parallel instead of in sequence.

I wrote some test code as per below. It works! It makes the request, processes it, timesOut for 3 second and goes to the second request.

```js
var batches = [of_objects];
var sequence = Promise.resolve();
var self = this;

sequence
    //Create request for first batch
    .then( function(){
        return self._createRequestPromise(batches[0]);
    })
    //callback so we can update, returns nothing
    .then(callback)
    //add 3 sec timeout before next request
    .then(function(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
        });
    })
    //Create request for second batch
    .then( function(){
        return self._createRequestPromise(batches[1]);
    })
    //callback so we can update, returns nothing
    .then(callback)
    //add 3 sec timeout before next request
    .then(function(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
        });
    });

return sequence;
```

BUT, as soon as I try to put it any sort of loop, my requests are firing all at the same time. And the timeout calls happen after.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or misunderstanding.

```js
//object I need to use to construct requests
var batches = [of_objects];
var sequence = Promise.resolve();
var self = this;

batches.forEach(function(batch){
    sequence
    //Function returns promise
    .then( function(){
        return self._createRequestPromise(batch); //this runs first 5x
    })
    //callback so we can update, returns nothing
    .then(callback)
    //add 3 sec timeout before next request
    .then(function(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(resolve, 3000); //this runs after 5x
        });
    });
});
return sequence;
```

Comment: The sequence is well written, you issue is the loop: It is not blocking so all you sequences are executed concurrently. This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40394679/6320039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're not updating `sequence` to include any of the successive operations, so all of them are chaining off of that original resolved promise. There's nothing there to delay any of them, so they execute right away.

You should be able to remedy this simply by updating the `sequence` variable on every loop, so you're chaining off the end of the chain:

```
//object I need to use to construct requests
var batches = [of_objects];
var sequence = Promise.resolve();
var self = this;

batches.forEach(function (batch){
    sequence = sequence            // <-- here
        //Function returns promise
        .then( function(){
            return self._createRequestPromise(batch); //this runs first 5x
        })
        //callback so we can update, returns nothing
        .then(callback)
        //add 3 sec timeout before next request
        .then(function(){
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                setTimeout(resolve, 3000); //this runs after 5x
            });
        });
});

return sequence;
```

Personally, I try to avoid overwriting variables, so an alternate way to do this without variable reassignment is to use `.reduce()`:

```
//object I need to use to construct requests
var batches = [of_objects];
var self = this;

return batches.reduce(function (last, batch){
    return last
        //Function returns promise
        .then( function(){
            return self._createRequestPromise(batch); //this runs first 5x
        })
        //callback so we can update, returns nothing
        .then(callback)
        //add 3 sec timeout before next request
        .then(function(){
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                setTimeout(resolve, 3000); //this runs after 5x
            });
        });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Great, the first answer does indeed solve my problem! I will do some more investigating as to why exactly.

Comment: Maybe for others, I actually started off with the reduce function when I first ran into the problem. My initial problem was that I returned last at the end, not chained like this answer. So two answers in one for me :)

Comment: @JeroendeLau I see, so you were basically making the same mistake in both attempts. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: absolutely thanks a bunch. You added new nugget of knowledge on the journey towards to promise proficiency ;)